# How to add a variable key in JSON?

Tags: node.js, json

I need to read a batch of files and make the filename as a JSON array. Code below this.moduleFiles.modulename = modules is not correct.

```
var fs = require("fs");
var loadRoute = {
  path : './api/modules/',
   moduleFiles : {},

   listDir : function(dir){
    console.log(dir);
    var fileList = fs.readdirSync(dir,'utf-8');
    for(var i=0;i<fileList.length;i++) {
        var stat = fs.lstatSync(dir + fileList[i]);
        if (stat.isDirectory()) {
            this.listDir(dir + fileList[i]  + '/');
        } else {
            this.loadRoute(dir + fileList[i]);
        }
    }
  },
  loadRoute : function(routeFile){
    // console.log('~~~~~~~~~~');
    console.log(routeFile);
    let modulename = routeFile.substring(0,routeFile.lastIndexOf('.'));
    modulename = modulename.substr(modulename.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)
    let modules = require('./modules/' + modulename);
    this.moduleFiles.modulename = modules

  },
  init : function(path){
    this.path = path?path:this.path;
    this.listDir(this.path);
    return this.moduleFiles;
  }
};

let x = loadRoute.init();
console.log(x);
```

I will only get

```
{ modulename: {..} } }
```

The expected results should like

```
{user: {...}, dep: {...}}
```

usr and dep are the modulename which from the filenames. any recommendation? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to require all modules from dir, use npm package [require-all](https://www.npmjs.com/package/require-all)

```
listDir : function(dir){
   this.moduleFiles = require('require-all')({
      dirname     :  dir,
      filter      :  /(.+routes)\.js$/, // some filter if you want
      excludeDirs :  /^\.(git|svn)$/,
      recursive   : true
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this.moduleFiles[{variable}] = modules, then you can get by this.moduleFiles.{variable}

this.moduleFiles.modulename = modules same as this.moduleFiles['modulename ']
so you cannot get what you want